# how can play a mp3 file in wpf by Media ToolKit

Tags: mediaelement

I am Using MediaUriElement of WpfMediaKit in my project but I Have problem in seeking the volume  to the Slider,Maby because the MediaUriElement dont have.how can seek the volume of my MediaUriElement to slider?